# How to allocate memory of a string in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I try to add a char array in my linked list using strcpy but in this case I have segmentation fault. I know how to allocate the memory for int but have trouble with char array. Do we need to use malloc especially for each char array of the linked list? This is my code :

```
typedef struct Avion Avion;
struct Avion
{
    char *NomAvion;
    char *NomCompanie;
    int Carburant;
    int place;
    Avion *suivant;
};

typedef struct Liste Liste;
struct Liste
{
        Avion *premier;
};

void AjouterUnAvion(Liste *liste)
{   
        char nomAvion1[20] = "defaultNomAvion";
        char nomCompanie1[20] = "defaultNomCompanie" ;
        scanf("%s",nomAvion1);
        scanf("%s",nomCompanie1);
        if(liste == NULL)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        Avion *nouvAv = malloc(sizeof(*nouvAv));
        strcpy(nouvAv->NomAvion,nomAvion1);
        strcpy(nouvAv->NomCompanie,nomCompanie1);
        
        Avion *current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
        current = liste->premier;
       
        while(current->suivant != NULL)
        {
            current = current->suivant;
        }
        current->suivant = nouvAv;
}

int main()
{
    Liste *liste = initialisationListe();
    AjouterUnAvion(liste);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two pointers inside your structure Avion. You should either allocate space for them (in order to use `strcpy`) or make it point to the arrays you have previously read.

Comment: Consider using `nouvAv->NomAvion = strdup(nomAvion1);` You can't store a pointer to `nomAvion1` because it will go out of scope and life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating more about the comment I've just made, when you called `Avion *nouvAv = malloc(sizeof(*nouvAv));`, it does not allocate space (I believe you want 20 chars for name and company, right?) for the pointers inside the structure. You could:

- make those struct members fixed size - like `char nom_avion[20]`
- allocate space for each of them, calling malloc (or any other function that allocates enough memory for you)
- make it point to existing and allocated permanent arrays with equals operator (be aware, when you make it inside a function for instance, the memory can be cleared and then the pointer would be pointing to nowhere)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have fixed my code and understood the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks guys, I'll try to fix my answer to make it more clearer and correct. Sorry I did it in kind of a hurry..

Comment: Ok, I've just updated it. If you have more feedbacks on my answer, feel free to add. Thanks again!